# Accessing random lines from a text file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, tkinter, text-files

I am creating a test like program and have a text file under QAfile that can be added to, with one line containing a question and the next line containing the corresponding answer. I would like to be able to output a random line containing a question and then the corresponding answer (from the next line) with questions being on even number lines (inc 0). How would I be able to output a random even numbered line with a question from the text file and then the corresponding answer in the following function ?

```
def TestMe():

    global QAfile
    global questionloc
    global answerloc
    global data

    try:
        with open(QAfile, 'r') as f:
            rootQA = Tk()
            rootQA.title('Question time')
            data = f.read().splitlines()
            lineNO = len(data)
            questionloc = random.randrange(0, lineNO, 2)     
            answerloc = questionloc + 1                      
            for questionloc in data:                         
                qlbl = Label(rootQA, text=data[questionloc]) 
                qlbl.pack()

                answerB = Button(rootQA, text='Answer?', command=Answer)
                answerB.grid(columnspan=10, sticky=W)
                answerB.pack(fill = 'x')

                repeatB = Button(rootQA, text='Another question', command=TestMe)
                repeatB.grid(columnspan=10, sticky=W)
                repeatB.pack(fill = 'x')

                HomeB = Button(rootQA, text='Done', command=LoggedIn)
                HomeB.grid(columnspan=10, sticky=W)
                HomeB.pack(fill = 'x')

def Answer():

    global data
    global answerloc

    with open(data) as f:
        rootA = Tk()
        rootA.title('Answer')
        Albl = Label(rootA, text=f[answerloc])    
        Albl.pack()
        rootA.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? What happens, what do you expect to happen, how do they differ? And zero is even, not odd. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: sorry, I meant even numbered lines including zero as these will be the ones with the questions

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you face is, that to know about the lines you have to read through the entire file. Should speed be an issue, there are various other methods to speed up counting the lines depending on the system you are using and your willingness to use shell commands from Python.

```
def get_q_a(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        numlines = sum(1 for _ in f)
    from random import choice
    target_line = choice(range(0, numlines-1, 2))
    with open(fname) as f:
        for _ in range(target_line):
            next(f)
        question, answer = next(f), next(f)
    return (question, answer)

question, answer = get_q_a('qaFile.txt')

# now there is question and answer available for further processing
```

P.S. Thanks to `Adam Smith` (see comments) for his efforts in improving this answer.

Comment: There's some fairly sizeable changes that could be made to this to make it look a little nicer. For instance `noOfLinesInFaile` should just be `numlines`. You can get that with `sum(1 for _ in f)`. You should avoid `readlines` in general. You don't need to do a compare for every line number, just do `for _ in range(randomLineNo): next(f)` so you don't need enumerate, etc. It's all small enough that I wouldn't want to re-write your correct answer, though.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand where the qaFile_Cg.py is for ? should this be the text file that is storing the questions and answers or is it something completely different ?

Comment: I'd probably re-write as [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c688829c17ed9c38e8d2f0fc7f06abbc)

Comment: I seem to be outputting answers instead of questions, could you explain ? the questions should be on even lines numbers inc zero and answers should be on odd numbered lines. The code works however sometimes outputs an answer as a question and then the question on the next line of the text file as the answer to the initial question.

Comment: (it seems to be an error in the code Adam Smith linked to his comment and which I took over that caused trouble ...) . is NOW all ok? According to my tests the proper line is the question and there is no Iteration Stop anymore...

Comment: yep everything seems to be working perfectly now thanks !